# Graviton-graviton scattering in tree level. Based on a talk by Bryce DeWitt

Tags: string-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-gravity, history, scattering-cross-section

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2935) talk given by Bryce DeWitt, at page 6 he mentions a problem he gave to one of his PhD students. The problem is to compute the graviton-graviton scattering amplitude in tree level approximation. He mentions that there were 4 relevant Feynman diagrams and a total of nearly 500 terms and that it wasn't a trivial calculation in the days when there were no computers. But the student did manage to calculate the answer and its

$$\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=4G^2E^2\frac{\cos^{12}\frac{1}{2}\theta}{\sin^4\frac{1}{2}\theta}$$

As DeWitt remarks, this is quite a simple answer considering the amount of calculations that are needed. Now I have 2 mains questions:

1. How did the student manage to calculate this amplitude, and in which framework?
2. DeWitt tells that this answer completely agrees with the amplitude we get from string theory for the same process. How is that amplitude calculated in string theory?

Comment: DeWitt’s classic 1967 [paper](https://blogs.umass.edu/grqft/files/2014/11/DeWitt-Quantum-gravity-3.pdf) has the details of how to calculate graviton-graviton scattering.

Comment: [Here](https://lup.lub.lu.se/luur/download?fileOId=8956261&func=downloadFile&recordOId=8956258) is a more recent treatment. “In this thesis we want to simplify the Feynman rules as much as possible by using the most general parameterized gauge condition, adding all possible parameterized total derivative terms and redefining the gravitational, ghosts and scalar fields in a general parameterization way. By choosing the parameters in a specific way, we obtain simplified Feynman rules, especially the triple and quadruple graviton vertices are simplified.”